# eloquent relationship hasManyThrough

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three models

- Markt
- Koppel_standhouders_markten
- Standhouders

Markt hasMany standhouders through an hasManyThrough koppel_standhouders_markten

The markt table has an id which matches markt_id in koppel_standhouders_markten. Koppel_standhouders_markten has an standhouder_id which matches the id of standhouders.

I defined my hasManyThrough as following:

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Models\Standhouder',
        'App\Models\Koppel_standhouders_markten',
        'markt_id', // Foreign key on Koppel_standhouders_markten table...
        'id', // Foreign key on Standhouder table...
        'id', // Local key on markt table...
        'standhouder_id' // Local key on Koppel_standhouders_markten table...
    );
```

I would see that this is correct but when I look at my data. It has matched the id of koppel_standhouders_markten to the id in Standhouders instead of getting the standhouder_id from koppel_standhouders_markten to match the id of standhouders.

Really hope someone can help me out. It must be something simple I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you got some parameters mixed up.

I think this is how you should define it:

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(
    'App\Models\Standhouder',
    'App\Models\Koppel_standhouders_markten',
    'markt_id',
    'standhouder_id'
);
```

The last 2 parameters are local ids, which you don't need to explicitly define since you're using the `id` column anyway.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'standhouders.standhouder_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `standhouders`.*, `koppel_standhouders_markten`.`markt_id` from `standhouders` inner join `koppel_standhouders_markten` on `koppel_standhouders_markten`.`id` = `standhouders`.`standhouder_id` where `koppel_standhouders_markten`.`markt_id` in (8))

This is what I get back from your example.

Comment: Before edit I mixed up last 2 (markt_id and standhouder_id). Check that you tried the updated version. Other then that, can you post the primary and foreign keys on all 3 tables. It'll be easier to reason about (and help) since we don't know the language.

Comment: I now what the problem is. This project was still using laravel 5.1. In this you only have the two parameters you told me. It is taking foreign keys which I do not want. I'm now going to update the entire project. The option I send is only usable from laravel 5.5. But thank you for the time taken.

Comment: @user3398922 No it's not. [Check the source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasManyThrough.php). You can pass first 5 arguments in the same way as in Laravel 5.5. The last 2 you don't need to explicitly define, unless your primary key is not `id`. Please try my updated version of the answer and let me know if you still get an error (and what error it is).

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was facing is that the hasManyThrough only 4 parameters. 2 for the models and 2 for foreign keys. It's not until laravel 5.5 that you can also enter local key's.